# Printing to IP receipt printer from ruby

Tags: ruby, macos, printing

Want to send text to a network receipt printer using ruby. I know the IP address of the printer. The printer is accessible through the network, but it is not directly connected to the computer.

I'm using a Star TSP100LAN, but I'm sure it would be using the same protocol as other receipt printers.

Answer (score 1):

almost all printers do speak PJL, the Printer Job Language. a simple TCP connection to printer IP should be sufficient. i don't know which port to use, but the PJL command set is well defined [here](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/bpl13208/bpl13208.pdf)(PDF).

Comment: Adrien, thanks for your answer, unfortunately my printer does not support PJL.

It supports CUPS
  system "lpr -P printer_name receipt.pdf"

But I want to be able to pass text directly to the printer rather than creating a PDF.